# Simple C++ downcast won't work for simple classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a generic `OpenFile` which represents an open file that I can downcast in my implementation which uses its own way to hold an open file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

class OpenFile {

};

class File : public OpenFile
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> file;
};


int main()
{
    OpenFile file;
    static_cast<File>(file).file;
    return 0;
}
```

However I'm getting

```
main.cpp:28:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘File::File(OpenFile&)’
     static_cast<File>(file).file;
```

I think it has to do with copy constructor but shouldn't it already get generated utomatically when I created

```
class File : public OpenFile
```

?

Update: I tried using pointers:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

class OpenFile {
public:
};

class File : public OpenFile
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> file;
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<OpenFile> file;
    auto f = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<File>(file);
    return 0;
}
```

But I get

```
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/shared_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::dynamic_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp2>&) [with _Tp = File; _Tp1 = OpenFile]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',26)">main.cpp:26:50</span>:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/shared_ptr.h:458:22: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘(& __r)->std::shared_ptr::.std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::get()’ (of type ‘class OpenFile*’) to type ‘class File*’ (source type is not polymorphic)
       if (_Tp* __p = dynamic_cast<_Tp*>(__r.get()))
```

Comment: Since `File` is derived from `OpenFile` you can say that `File` is a `OpenFile`.  Does that also mean that a `OpenFile` is a `File`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica not always but C++ downcasting is possible. Why it won't work?

Comment: Downcasting is allowed (with `dynamic_cast`) if you have a pointer/reference of type `OpenFile` that points to an object of type `File`. That is not the case here. The only object is of type `OpenFile`. Why do you think you need this cast?

Comment: @uneven_mark I want to have an interface (.h file) which holds an OpenFile, but I want to be able to initiate this File object in my class declaration

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs What does "*initiate this File object in my class declaration*" mean? Maybe you should add a complete example of the use case you envision to the question.

Comment: @uneven_mark I updated the usage with pointers but I'm still getting errors. Can you take a look?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You need to make `OpenFile` polymorphic e.g. by adding a virtual destructor: `virtual ~OpenFile() {}`. Also `shared_ptr` does not automatically point to an object. It will be empty initially. You need to make it point to an object (of type `File`), otherwise the result of the cast is simply another empty `shared_ptr` without any actual casting happening.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not copyable.